# Parking lot problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have found similar questions in these links ([1](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Probability-and-statistics/Probability-and-statistics.faq.question.1144868.html),[2](https://questions.llc/questions/1013582/mary-and-tom-park-their-cars-in-an-empty-parking-lot-with-n-2-consecutive-parking),[3](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/ukjwkn/question_about_the_parking_lot_problem/)), but none of them is from CrossValidated (and I still don't grasp the solution, so here I am).

The problem is this:

> Tom and Jerry park their cars in an empty parking lot with `n>=2`
> consecutive parking spaces (i.e,  spaces in a row, where only one car
> fits in each space). Tom and Jerry pick parking spaces at random; of
> course, they must each choose a different space. (All pairs of
> distinct parking spaces are equally likely.) What is the probability,
> in terms of `n`, that there is at most one empty parking space between
> them?

The solution is $\frac{2(2n-3)}{n(n-1)}$. I understand that the total possibilities are $n(n-1)$ as the first person to park his car has `n` possibilities and the second person has `n` possibilities minus the spot the first person parked, which would be $n-1$. Hence, the universe is $n(n-1)$. However, I don't get how to get the numerator. Can anyone explain it with apples, please?

I tried finding the pattern using `n=2`, `n=3`, `n=4`, and so on.. without success. As you can see here:

[image]

Where:

- Each cell represents a parking spot and each row a possibility. `1` means if that possibility fulfills the restriction of the problem (*at most one parking spot between them*), `0` otherwise. The fraction is the number of occurrences that fulfills the restriction over the total universe (the probability, in other words).

I am trying two things here: The first is to grasp this problem and its details and the second is to find an efficient way to solve this problem. Why? Because I will have to solve similar problems in a future exam and this would be really helpful!

**EDIT**: Solution corrected

Comment: There is no need to discern Tom and Jerry. Just think in pairs of spaces. One of these pairs is picked out.

Comment: Well, all answers match now (i.e. after your edit) with the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Tom and Jerry together randomly pick out a pair of parking spaces.

There are $\binom{n}2$ **equiprobable** pairs of parking spaces.

$n-1$ of the pairs consist of spaces that are not separated by any empty space.

$n-2$ of the pairs consist of spaces that are separated by exactly one empty space.

So: $$(n-1)+(n-2)=2n-3$$ of the pairs consist of spaces that are separated by at most one empty space.

Then the probability that Tom and Jerry pick out a pair consisting of spaces that are separated by at most one empty space equals:$$\frac{2n-3}{\binom{n}2}=\frac{4n-6}{n(n-1)}$$This based on the rule that probability equals number of favourable outcomes divided by number of possible outcomes. This rule works if the outcomes are equiprobable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you fix the position of the first car and then you calculate the possible positions for the second car where the distance is equal to or less than 1 car.

T at Position 1: 2 desired positions out of $n-1$

T at Position 2: 3 desired positions out of $n-1$

T at Position 2<i<n-1: 4 desired positions out of $n-1$

T at Position n-1: 3 desired positions out of $n-1$

T at Position n: 2 desired positions out of $n-1$

The total probability will be:

$$P=\Sigma_{i=1}^{i=n}{P(\text{distance between T and J} \leq 1)}P(\text{T at position i}) $$

$$=\frac{1}{n} (\frac{2}{n-1}+\frac{3}{n-1}+\frac{4}{n-1}+...+\frac{4}{n-1}+\frac{3}{n-1}+\frac{2}{n-1}) 
=\frac{1}{n} (\frac{4n-2-1-1-2}{n-1})
=\frac{1}{n} (\frac{4n-6}{n-1})$$